# How can I show related products in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layout

I am using Magento 1.9 with porto theme. i want to show related product in product page . I searched a lot on google , stack platform & in magento community. i tried all possible ways to add related products but failed . does anyone know exactly how to show related products ? I do reindex from

> Login to Admin
> Go to System -> Index Management
> Select All checkboxes
> Select 'Reindex Data' from Actions selection list
> Click Submit button
> I tried various method to add related products in product page as given in other posts like edit  in Catalog.xml & view.phtml . Unfortunately I Stuck , If any one know kindly help me.

Comment: check this links --- https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-relationships-related-products.html, https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-product-relations.html

Comment: I do these things , but Related products are not showing ,Only UP-Sells are showing

Comment: you run cache and index in admin ???

Comment: UP-Sells products title is "ALSO PURCHASED" If you know how to change title, guide me then i will change title to Related products

Comment: yes , i run  cache and index from admin

Comment: find UP-Sells products file...

Comment: where i can find UP-Sells file ?

Comment: i think this `catalog/product/view.phtml`

Comment: i found up-sell file in public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product/list
and change title to related products :)